# RMSE and MAE for comparing pearson correlation coefficients?

Tags: correlation, model-comparison

Lets say I have a measured set B and predicted set C, I compute their Pearson correlation coefficient with A which is the ground truth set and let these coefficients be r1 and r2. I wanted to understand why RMSE and MAE of r1 and r2 are not appropriate ways of comparing the correlations?

The experiment concerns control flow analysis of a program running on a microcontroller by observing power consumption of the microcontroller. This program has an "If block" and an "Else block" and I expect the power consumption to vary based on which block is taken. These blocks are within a conditional loop that executes n times. Set A is the ground truth pattern of the sequence of "If block" and "Else block" in n executions. I measure multiple power consumption traces B1,B2...BM and I correlate them with set A. Each measurement is independent of the other. I have another power consumption trace C which is predicted and I correlate that with set A as well. I'm trying to find a statistical measure to say that my predicted trace C closely models the measured traces B1,B2..BM using these correlations

Comment: Could you give a less abstract description of what you are doing? Maybe describe it in terms of the actual data you are using and the actual procedure? From your description, I can't say what you're doing, it sounds as if you take two numbers (the correlation coefficients) and calculate their absolute difference $\sqrt{(r_1 - r_2)^2} = |r_1 - r_2|$, but this has nothing to do with RMSE or MSE in their usual meaning.

Comment: @Tim I have added the edit to the question

Comment: Why not use correlation coefficients themselves as "error" metrics or not calculate RMSE for the predicted values vs ground truth directly?

Comment: @Tim The predicted values (voltage levels) and ground truth(binary 1 and 0 ) have different units so I'm not sure if RMSE can be used. I was thinking more along computing a z-score for the correlation coefficient of the predicted trace using the sampling distribution of the correlation coefficients of the measured traces. Does that make sense? How do I use the correlation coefficients as "error" metrics ?

Comment: The usual statistical approach would be to treat the predicted values (voltage) that are used to predict the probability of the ground truth events (e.g. logistic regression). In such a case, they would be on the same scale. Can't you translate the predicted voltage to the similar units as ground truth?

Comment: @Tim the ground truth is just a sequence of 1's and 0's where a 1 represents an "If block" being taken and a 0 represents an "Else block" being taken. I want the correlation analysis to show that the measured traces for an "If block" and "Else block" are different and that my predicted trace concurs with it. If I translate then I might be introducing bias.

Comment: OK. Correlation by itself tells you how good is the fit, why not use it directly? Notice however that correlation measures only the *linear* relationship.

Comment: @Tim I can, lets say the measured traces gave correlations 0.76,0.8,0.9,0.95...0.96 and the predicted was 0.86. I'm trying to figure out a way to summarize and put this in a paper. Ideally I want a single number or rather my advisor wants a single number to indicate good match between the predicted and measured traces. I was hoping if z-score is a good measure

Comment: Can't you just publish something like the average, min, and max?

Comment: @Kevin This sounds majorly like an XY problem where you have issue X that you think you can solve if you can figure out Y, so you ask about Y instead of X (very common to do this). What is your problem X?